# Regex to select everything but a pattern of 13 digits in a row

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a String such as

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/123_05547898_8101060027367_00.jpeg
```

, and using Regex & NodeJs, I need to select everything except a pattern of 13 digits in a row (i.e. without other char types between digits).

Thus, I'm expecting to select:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/123_05547898__00.jpeg
```

In other words, I would need the opposite of

```
\d{13}
```

Anyone got an idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then use `.replace()` to remove these 13 digits from your string.

Comment: Actually, I have to comply with an already existing system, which is already using replace(regex, ''). Thus I need to select the opposite, to keep the 13 digits pattern only.

Comment: Like `replace(/\d{13}|(.)/g, '$1')`? Or, do you need to check for underscores on both ends? Then you need `(_)\d{13}(?=_)|(.)` => `$1$2`

Comment: Is there a way avoiding using grouping such as $1 ?

Comment: No, because there is no regex construct like "match some text other than a sequence of more than one character". And you cannot emulate it another way in JS.

Comment: Ok, then I will use your solution. I just have to manage groups :-). Thank @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
text.replace(/\d{13}|(.)/g, '$1')
text.replace(/(_)\d{13}(?=_)|(.)/g, '$1$2') // only in between _s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vh4l05/1).

The `\d{13}|(.)` pattern matches thirteen digits or any one char other than line break chars (LF and CR) while capturing it into Group 1. To put back this char, the `$1` backreference is used in the replacement pattern.

Note there is no regex construct like "match some text other than a sequence of more than one character" (it is only supported in Lucene regex flavor that is rather a specific regex flavor). There is no way to emulate such a construct in JavaScript (it is possible in PCRE where you can use an alternation with `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` and a tempered greedy token).